# Assigning restangular getList results to $scope

Tags: angularjs, restangular

So it looks like in the examples you can do this:

```
App.controller('ProjectListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
  $scope.projects = Restangular.all('project/').getList();
}]);
```

But that doesn't work for me. When I ng-repeat project in projects and look at the scope, I see:

```
{ 
projects:  { 
  then: null
  catch: null
  finally: null
  call: null
  get: null
  restangularCollection: true
  push: null
 } 
}
```

Which looks like an un resolved promise object right?

This works fine but is more verbose:

```
lgtApp.controller('ProjectListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
  Restangular.all('project/').getList().then(function(projects){            
    $scope.projects = projects;                                             
  });                                                                       
}]);
```

Did I miss something? This is in the docs:

```
$scope.owners = house.getList('owners')
```

Shouldn't matter, but this happens when I'm testing a phonegap app in the Ripple chrome plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of angular 1.2, automatic unwrapping of promises was disabled and deprecated. So, while

```
$scope.projects = Restangular.all('project/').getList();
```

would have allowed you to access `projects` in your view directly in previous releases (for which the Restangular docs where likely written), that will no longer work automatically. You can reenable the feature via the `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises()` API, but it is deprecated, so your best bet is probably to manually resolve the promise in your controller like in your more verbose example.

See the checkin [commit message](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577) for more details.

Answer (score 12):

```
$scope.projects = Restangular.all('project/').getList().$object;
```

Comment: In the current version (Restangular 1.5.1, Angular 1.3.15) this approach seems to work, as the actual array is within the property, `$object`.

Answer (score 9):

As an addition to the other comment, even though promise unwrapping was disabled, I implemented in Restangular a new way of having promises unwrap easily for you (Similar to what $resource does what without removing Promises). Check https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#using-values-directly-in-templates for more information :)

Comment: Don't seem to be having much luck with this. Its returning an empty array - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844177/restangular-data-getting-into-scope-for-a-list