# Restangular data, getting into $scope for a list

Tags: angularjs, restangular, steroids

Been wrestling with API stuff all day, and decided to use Restanglar. Really having issues getting the data out, and into $scope.

I understand that it won't just be the JSON that is returned from the API, and has a bunch of other internal methods etc. But when I get the data out, I can see it buried somewhere in the debugging with console.log, but I can't seem to get it into $scope to use it in my view which was working fine previously.

**How can I get that data out into my $scope, and therefore my view?**

Model

```
angular.module('horse', ['restangular'])
    .config(function(RestangularProvider) {
        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://url/api');

        RestangularProvider.setResponseInterceptor(
          function(data, operation, what) {
            if (operation == 'getList') {
              return data[what];
            }
            return data;
        });
});
```

Controller

```
angular
  .module('horse')
  .controller("IndexController", function ($scope, Restangular) {
    $scope.horse = null;
    $scope.showSpinner = true;

    Restangular.all('horse').getList().then(function(horse) {
        $scope.horse = horse;
        console.log($scope.horse);
    });
});
```

API response

```
{"error":false,"horse":[{"id":"1","name":"horse 2"},{"id":"2","name":"horse 2"}]}
```

***Edit 1***

Restangular response

```
[Object, Object, route: "horse", getRestangularUrl: function, getRequestedUrl: function, addRestangularMethod: function, clone: function…]
```

[image: Restangular expanded console.log output]

***Edit 2***

I have also tried this - https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#using-values-directly-in-templates

`$scope.horse = Restangular.all('horse').getList().$object;`

Which just results in an empty array being output. I have also tried removing the `setResponseInterceptor` and modifying the structure of the api to result the data array directly without the meta stuff (error, etc), no joy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data seems to be coming through. I notice you're using Steroids, have you checked the markup and not just the console?

Make sure you set the scope spinner to false, to ensure that the spinner is hidden when the data comes through.

`$scope.ShowSpinner = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you have shown as "API response" is what's getting outputted from the console.log in your controller, it seems that all you need to do is set your scope model the the property "horse" in the response data like this:

```js
$scope.horse = horse.horse;
```

Since that reads pretty oddly, you should change the param name of the .then callback to data, which would be a much more agnostic and standard param name. If you make that change you can set your horse data to your scope model from inside your callback like this:

```js
$scope.horse = data.horse;
```

If I misunderstood your question let me know. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: thanks for the response, sorry I should have been more clear, the API response was what I get when I goto the appropriate URL with a REST client in my browser. I have now added what I get back from Restangular, which seems to be a bunch of other stuff. I can see the data buried in the 'Restangularized' response, but it doesn't seem to be easily accessible and I can't believe its that difficult to get out so I must be doing something stupid ;)